# Symfony 3: allow_delete in Forms not working

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a problem with my form in Symfony 3. I have **one-to-many-to-one join** (Doctrine 2). It handles Orders (**Order**), Products (**Product**) and joining entity (**OrderProduct**), which holds amount of product in order.

I have a **form** for **add and update** order entries, which uses **Collection of OrderProducts**. It's all based on documentation ([link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)).

In the form I have a **button for add a product** (from documentation, adds a <li> to DOM) and every added has a **button for remove it** (from documentation, removes <li> from DOM). This part is working - adding to and removing from DOM.

Adding products works (as at the new order, than when editting).

But my problem is with removing. Products which was **succesfully deleted from form**, are **still appearing** in *$editForm->getData()*.

**OrderProduct Form**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\ProductType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class OrderProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('amount')
            ->add('product')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\OrderProduct',
            )
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_order_product_type';
    }
}
```

**Order Form**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class OrderType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('customer')
            ->add('date', null, array('widget' => 'single_text'))
            ->add('payment', null, array('widget' => 'single_text'))
            ->add('processed', null, array('widget' => 'single_text'))
            ->add(
                'orderProducts',
                CollectionType::class,
                array(
                    'entry_type'    => OrderProductType::class,
                    'allow_add'     => true,
                    'allow_delete'  => true,
                    'by_reference'  => false,
                    'prototype'     => true,
                    'delete_empty'  => true,
                    'entry_options' => array('data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\OrderProduct'),
                )
            );

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_order_type';
    }

}
```

**Current action in OrderController**
*(Adding product works, removing not)*
    public function editAction (Request $request, $orderId) {

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $order = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')->find($orderId);

    if (!$order) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No order found for id '.$orderId);
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(OrderType::class, $order);
    $editForm->add('submit', SubmitType::class);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

        $order = $editForm->getData();

        //print '<pre>';
        //var_dump($order->getOrderProducts());
        //die();

        $orderProducts = $order->getOrderProducts();

        $em->persist($order);

        foreach ($orderProducts as $oneOrderProduct) {
            $oneOrderProduct->setOrder($order);
            $em->persist($oneOrderProduct);
        }

        //print '<pre>';
        //var_dump($order->getOrderProducts());
        //die();

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('one_order', array('orderId' => $order->getId()));
    }


    return $this->render(
        'order/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $editForm->createView(),
    ));

}
```

I know that I must remove removed OrderProducts from Order in editAction, but now I can't, because from the form is sent all OrderProducts.

**Order Entity**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity\OrderProduct;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="order_")
 */
class Order
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="orders")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $customer;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $date;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $payment;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $processed;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return strval($this->getId());
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderProduct", mappedBy="order")
     */
    private $orderProducts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orderProducts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set payment
     *
     * @param \DateTime $payment
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setPayment($payment)
    {
        $this->payment = $payment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get payment
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getPayment()
    {
        return $this->payment;
    }

    /**
     * Set processed
     *
     * @param \DateTime $processed
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setProcessed($processed)
    {
        $this->processed = $processed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get processed
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getProcessed()
    {
        return $this->processed;
    }

    /**
     * Set customer
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Customer $customer
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setCustomer(\AppBundle\Entity\Customer $customer = null)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Customer
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    /**
     * Add orderProduct
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\OrderProduct $orderProduct
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function addOrderProduct(\AppBundle\Entity\OrderProduct $orderProduct)
    {
        $this->orderProducts[] = $orderProduct;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove orderProduct
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\OrderProduct $orderProduct
     */
    public function removeOrderProduct(\AppBundle\Entity\OrderProduct $orderProduct)
    {
        $this->orderProducts->removeElement($orderProduct);
    }

    /**
     * Get orderProducts
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getOrderProducts()
    {
        return $this->orderProducts;
    }
}
```

But in POST it's OK [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s05kV.png), here I removed 2 of 4 products. Problem appears in form handling.

Comment: Why there is no `data_class` defined in `OrderType`? Can you share the `Order` Entity and Controller?

Comment: Yes, `data_class` was missing in OrderType, I added it (in other Forms it's OK).

I added `Order` entity and `editAction` from `OrderController` to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it last night :)

This is working controller action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{orderId}/edit", name="edit_order", requirements={"orderId": "\d+"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param         $orderId
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, $orderId)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $order = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')->find($orderId);

    if (!$order) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('new_order');
    }

    $originalOrderProducts = new ArrayCollection();

    foreach ($order->getOrderProducts() as $orderProduct) {
        $originalOrderProducts->add($orderProduct);
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(OrderType::class, $order);
    $editForm->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

        $orderProducts = $order->getOrderProducts();

        foreach ($originalOrderProducts as $oneOriginalOrderProduct) {
            if (false === $order->getOrderProducts()->contains($oneOriginalOrderProduct)) {
                $order->removeOrderProduct($oneOriginalOrderProduct);
                $em->remove($oneOriginalOrderProduct);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }

        foreach ($orderProducts as $oneOrderProduct) {
            if ($oneOrderProduct->getAmount() == 0) {
                $order->removeOrderProduct($oneOrderProduct);
                $em->remove($oneOrderProduct);
            } else {
                if (!$originalOrderProducts->contains($oneOrderProduct)) {
                    $oneOrderProduct->setOrder($order);
                }
                $em->persist($oneOrderProduct);
            }
            $em->persist($order);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('order');
    }

    return $this->render('order/new.html.twig', array('form' => $editForm->createView()));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by_reference is set to false the underlying Order entity MUST have a method in your case called [removeOrderProduct]. What also might be the problem is that you are not specifying data_class option inside the configureOptions method. In your case if Order entity is in 'AppBundle\Entity\Order', then the configureOptions method should contain:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Order',
    ));
}
```

And I would suggest you do the same in OrderProductType class also. 
My guess would be that since you haven't specified the 'data_class' option in your OrderType class, the by_reference option in the 'orderProducts' field might not be able to figure out where to look for the [removeOrderProduct] method. So set that option and make sure you have that method inside your Order entity class.

IF this is not the problem then you should provide more information about your order entity and where exactly are you calling the getData method.

Update:

Looking at your code I can't identify the problem, that might be causing the entities to not get removed. But I have spotted a few oddities in your code:

In the controller, when handling form submittions it is not necessary to call the getData method: after you call handleRequest the $order object gets updated and holds the new information (since objects are passed by reference, the form can't apply the changes without changing the original $order as well). So there is no need to $order = $form->getData(), since you have already defined the $order variable before and it holds the reference to the same object to which the form mapped the posted values.

If that does not help, I suggest you add die; statements all over the place, just to make sure that at each step the right methods are called. For instance add die; to the removeOrderProduct method, to check if its hit. If it was hit, the problem is not going to be evident from the data you have provided to us, so it will require further debugging.

Also it might not be a problem now, but if you want to remove the products not present in the list after submittion, you have to call $order->getOrderProducts and add each of the items to a new collection that holds the previous orderProducts (before submittion) and compare that to the values after submittion to figure out which ones need removing.

Comment: Yes, missing `data_class` was mistake, I added it.

Method `removeOrderProduct` exist in `Order`.

I added the entity and `editAction` to question.